# How can I get a value from .getVisibleText() to my variable?

Tags: intern

How can I get a value from .getVisibleText() to my variable?

.getVisibleText return a command object to use .then with it. But is there any way to get the text to my own variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Writing a functional test](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#writing-functional-test) shows an example that would make want to try

```
define(function (require) {
  var registerSuite = require('intern!object');

  registerSuite(function() {
    var YOUR_VARIABLE;

    return {
      name: 'index',

      'greeting form': function() {
        return this.remote
          .get(require.toUrl('index.html'))
          .setFindTimeout(5000)
          .findById('greeting')
            .getVisibleText()
            .then(function (text) {
              YOUR_VARIABLE = text;
            });
      }
    };
  });
});
```